# Deploy rails app on AWS directly from C9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, c9.io

I got a notification that AWS recently tookover C9 IDE.

I was curious that, have they provided any way to deploy the Rails Project on AWS server through C9? Or anything that links between them which makes the Job easier?

Comment: Push to "Github" then Deploy to AWS.

Comment: I know it can be pushed into `GIT` and deployed. I wanted to know if there is any other means they have provided.

Comment: Just noticed, C9 was taked by AWS :) Probably, you are able to deploy through it. Gluck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, C9 is under AWS now and you can follow the guide provided by AWS website straight away to setup the C9 account: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/)

Be notified that if you do not have a account then have to create it with your genuine credit/debit card. Some other points to be noted are

1. They provide free account for an year but if u exceed the free limit they will charge you.
2. push your C9 data to git or bitbucket (free upto 5 users)
3. AWS RDS: create it with (t2.micro) which is free and above this you will charged more
4. If you do not want AWS RDS, then you can use remote DB credentials which i prefer you to use because it will save you a lot of money.
5. Install RDS DB and allow that DB to C9 by visiting security groups of RDS
6. If you are installing postgresql for C9 then install it as u install in Ubuntu or other linux machine. Below are some of the commands

To install postgresql

> sudo apt-get install -y postgis postgresql
>
> pip install psycopg2
>
> or
>
> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
>
> pip install psycopg2

Happy coding!